# Cakephp validation bug in controller?

Tags: cakephp, invalidation

I am trying to invalidate a field by a condition in controller instead of Model.

```
$this->Model->invalidate('check_out_reason', __('Please specify check out reason.', true));
```

The above won't work to invalidate the field. Instead, I need the below:

```
$this->Model->invalidate('Model.check_out_reason', __('Please specify check out reason.', true));
```

However, if I wish get the error message show up in the "field" itself ($this->model->validationErrors), it needs to be "check_out_reason" instead of "Model.check_out_reason". That means, I can't get the error message to show up in the field itself if I wish to invalidate the input in controller.

May I know is this a bug in CakePHP?

Comment: Seems like a major league bug to me, especially since we are already calling "invalidate" on a specific Model. We shouldn't need to repeat it in the "field" parameter.

Answer (score 1):

i created a test controller called "Invoices", just for testing, and i developed the following function

```
public function index(){
            if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Invoice->invalidate('nombre', __('Please specify check out reason.'));
                if ($this->Invoice->validates()) {
                // it validated logic
                        if($this->Invoice->save($this->request->data)){
                            # everthing ok
                        } else {
                            # not saved
                        }
                } else {
                    // didn't validate logic
                    $errors = $this->Invoice->validationErrors;

                }
            }
        }
```

i think it worked for me
[image]

Change the field "nombre" for your field called "check_out_reason" to adapt the function to your code

Comment: Hi pedro, doesn't work for me. What is your index.ctp?
here is mine:
<?php echo $this->Form->create('invoices') ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('invoices.nombre') ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end('submit') ?>

Comment: and I am trying with cakephp 2.2.0 / 2.2.3

Comment: <?php
echo $this->Form->create();

echo $this->Form->input('nombre');   
//echo $this->Form->error('nombre');   

echo $this->Form->end('Add');
?>

Comment: yep, this is the best answer -- you have to call "validates" before "save" on the model in question. Totally stupid that this is the case, but there ya go.

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for manual invalidates from controller. Reading a lot on this issue I found out that the save() function doesn't take in consideration the invalidations set through invalidate() function called in controller, but (this is very important) if it is called directly from the model function beforeValidate() it's working perfectly.

So I recommend to go in AppModel.php file and create next public methods:

```
public $invalidatesFromController = array();

public function beforeValidate($options = array()) {
    foreach($this->invalidatesFromController as $item){
       $this->invalidate($item['fieldName'], $item['errorMessage'], true);
    }        
    return parent::beforeValidate($options);
}

public function invalidateField($fieldName, $errorMessage){
    $this->invalidatesFromController[] = array(
        'fieldName' => $fieldName,
        'errorMessage' => $errorMessage
    );
}
```

After that, make sure that your model's beforeValidate() function calls the parent's one:

```
public function beforeValidate($options = array()) {
    return parent::beforeValidate($options);
}
```

In your controller for invalidating a field use next line:

```
$this->MyModel->invalidateField('fieldName', "error message");
```

Hope it helps! For me it's working!